# Scrubbing Names via SQL Query/Batch

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, scripting

We have sensitive information (names of people) and we're looking to put into place a script to "scrub" of the names.  Has anybody come up with a good algorithm to do this, something other than just making all of the last names "TEST" or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to do this for NPI (non-public information) reasons at a previous employer.  Ended up scrambling fields in a script, since a first name / last name pair isn't NPI unless it's tied to something else.

Here's a rough version of the script.  Season to taste.  Also, this assumes you have first and last names in separate fields.

```
CREATE TABLE #RandomData
(
    DataID int not null,
    ID int not null,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #RandomData (ID, DataID)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()), DataId FROM DataTable

UPDATE r SET r.FirstName = x.FirstName
FROM #RandomData r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS ID, FirstName FROM DataTable
) x
    ON x.ID = r.ID

UPDATE r SET r.LastName = x.LastName
FROM #RandomData r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS ID, LastName FROM DataTable
) x
    ON x.ID = r.ID

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_RandomData ON #RandomData
(
    DataID asc
)

ALTER TABLE DataTable DISABLE TRIGGER ALL

UPDATE dt 
    SET dt.FirstName = r.FirstName, 
    dt.LastName = r.LastName
FROM DataTable dt
INNER JOIN #RandomData r
    ON dt.DataId = r.DataId

ALTER TABLE DataTable ENABLE TRIGGER ALL

DROP TABLE #RandomData
```

Comment: This works very well, nice job.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to know what the name is but for whatever reason you want to keep something in the table for that record, you can always just use a [hash of the name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Name = HASHBYTES('SHA1', Name)
```

This will keep a unique value for each name record, but you will have no way to know what the name is.  You can, however, see if a name matches a value by comparing an hashed input to the stored hash.

Cryptographic hashes like this are one way, so you can create an identical hash from an identical input string, but not determine the input string even if you know what the hash is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks to [this function](http://techbrat.blogspot.com/2012/12/scrambled.html) name and surname like **Jack Sparrow** will become **Dchv Dkiokmd** and e-mail like **Jack.Sparrow@pirate27.biz** will become **Ninj.Sdkpiqy@wywmky53.kdd**:

```
-------------------------------------------------

--A view to give you Random Values
CREATE VIEW dbo.random(value) AS SELECT RAND();

GO
-------------------------------------------------

--Randomization Procedure
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnRandomizedText (
@OldValue AS VARCHAR(MAX)
)RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)

BEGIN

  DECLARE @NewValue AS VARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @nCount AS INT
  DECLARE @cCurrent AS CHAR(1)
  DECLARE @cScrambled AS CHAR(1)
  DECLARE @Random AS REAL
 
  SET @NewValue = ''
  SET @nCount = 0
   WHILE (@nCount <= LEN(@OldValue))
  BEGIN
    SELECT @Random = value FROM random
    SET @cCurrent = SUBSTRING(@OldValue, @nCount, 1)
     IF ASCII(@cCurrent) BETWEEN ASCII('a') AND ASCII('z')
       SET @cScrambled = CHAR(ROUND(((ASCII('z') - ASCII('a') - 1) * @Random + ASCII('a')), 0))
    ELSE IF ASCII(@cCurrent) BETWEEN ASCII('A') AND ASCII('Z')
       SET @cScrambled = CHAR(ROUND(((ASCII('Z') - ASCII('A') - 1) * @Random + ASCII('A')), 0))
    ELSE IF ASCII(@cCurrent) BETWEEN ASCII('0') AND ASCII('9')
       SET @cScrambled = CHAR(ROUND(((ASCII('9') - ASCII('0') - 1) * @Random + ASCII('0')), 0))
    ELSE
       SET @cScrambled = @cCurrent

    SET @NewValue = @NewValue + @cScrambled
    SET @nCount = @nCount + 1

  END
   RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@NewValue))
END
GO 
-------------------------------------------------
```

You can then update your tables just like this.

```
UPDATE my_Users_table SET UserName = dbo.fnRandomizedText(UserName), LoweredUserName = dbo.fnRandomizedText(LoweredUserName)
```